# swiftmailer from address stops email delivery

Tags: php, email, subdomain, swiftmailer

I have an application which uses swiftmailer to send an email when you change your password.

The application exists on a subdomain like this app.domain.com and not www.domain.com which is reserved for a sales site for the application.

In order to make the swiftmailer send the email, i have to set the setFrom() and setSender() email addresses to support@app.domain.com which is not correct as it should be support@domain.com

However as soon as i remove the app. part from the setSender() and setFrom() email addresses the email is never sent.

Any ideas why this could be? They are not being sent to my junk folder.

Comment: If you're using an SMTP server, is it set up to accept mail being sent from that domain?

Comment: im using the send() method

Comment: are you sure its not sent? have you checked your outgoing mail logs?

Comment: Ah. The log showed an address verification failer which i have now resolved. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.